# Error creating PDF in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, pdf, manifest

Im trying to make a PDF using android text and the log gives me this message when I try to generate it:

```
07-29 19:45:23.682: D/PDFCreator(12569): PDF Path: /mnt/sdcard/droidText
07-29 19:45:23.682: E/PDFCreator(12569): ioException:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/droidText/sample.pdf (Permission denied)
07-29 19:45:27.456: D/PDFCreator(12569): PDF Path: /mnt/sdcard/droidText
07-29 19:45:27.456: E/PDFCreator(12569): ioException:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/droidText/sample.pdf (Permission denied)
```

Heres my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ex.pruebapdf"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ex.pruebapdf.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Ill appreciate the help.

Heres the mainactivity.java, its a preformatted code I found on the internet. :

```
package com.ex.pruebapdf;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Font;
import com.lowagie.text.FontFactory;
import com.lowagie.text.HeaderFooter;
import com.lowagie.text.Image;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
import com.lowagie.text.Phrase;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button b;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b= (Button)findViewById(R.id.botoncin);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            createPDF();

        }
    });
}

public void createPDF()
{
    Document doc = new Document();


     try {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/droidText";

            File dir = new File(path);
                if(!dir.exists())
                    dir.mkdirs();

            Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);


            File file = new File(dir, "sample.pdf");
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

            PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

            //open the document
            doc.open();


            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Hi! I am generating my first PDF using DroidText");
            Font paraFont= new Font(Font.COURIER);
            p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
            p1.setFont(paraFont);

             //add paragraph to document    
             doc.add(p1);

             Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("This is an example of a simple paragraph");
             Font paraFont2= new Font(Font.COURIER,14.0f,Color.GREEN);
             p2.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
             p2.setFont(paraFont2);

             doc.add(p2);

             ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
             myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

             //add image to document
             doc.add(myImg);

             //set footer
             Phrase footerText = new Phrase("This is an example of a footer");
             HeaderFooter pdfFooter = new HeaderFooter(footerText, false);
             doc.setFooter(pdfFooter);



     } catch (DocumentException de) {
             Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
     } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
     } 
     finally
     {
             doc.close();
     }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may sound weird but have you checked your phone has a SD card. Just a notice because I made that mistake before. In addition, when you create the file, check if you use the correct mode, in case your PDF is created by other activities.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have to create the file before putting into text. But you should post some code.

EDIT 1:

Error is here?

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/droidText";
```

If not post the row where error is.

In case it is the above, I think you don't have any external storage (like an SD card). Do you? In that case try this:

You can get internal storage path using

```
context.getCacheDir();
```

You can create file doing:

```
File temp = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"you_file_name");
```